# Why is my HTML code showing in my forms text area?

Tags: html, forms, web

I'm trying to create a two column form in HTML using the below code.

```
<div id="form-wrapper">
  <form class="contact_form" action="" method="post" name="contact_form">
    <ul>
      <div id="form_left">
        <li>
          <span class="required_field"> * Denotes a required field</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label for="name">Name:</label>
          <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="John Doe">
        </li>
        <li>
          <label for="telephone">Contact Number:</label>
          <input type="tel" name="telephone" placeholder="(01225) 123456">
        </li>
        <li>
          <label for="email">Email:</label>
          <input type="email" name="email address" placeholder="example@example.com">
        </li>
      </div>  
      <div id="form_right">
        <li>
          <label for="message">Message:</label>
          <textarea name="message" cols="40" rows="6" >
        </li>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </form>
</div>
```

(http://jsfiddle.net/qrttZ/)

But for some reason, it is showing the bottom half of my HTML code inside of the text area window.

I can't see any open tags so i'n not sure why this is.

Comment: A validator would answer your question. Hint: you're missing a closing tag.

Comment: `<ul>` then `<div>` then  `<li>`? Please look up HTML list elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact that HTML doesn't need the XHTML self closing short tags, e.g. `<input />` means it's very easy for rookies to make this mistake as `textarea` performs a very similar purpose. It's just that for a very good reason it needs closing.

```
<textarea name="message" cols="40" rows="6" ></textarea>
```

...

That done, this

```
<ul>
   <div id="form_left">
      <li>
```

is bad. `<li>` show follow `<ul>` there should not be a `<div>` there.

Also

```
<label for="name">Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="John Doe">
```

Without an `id` in the input, that `for` is useless.

```
<label for="name">Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="John Doe">
```

But if you're going to use a label with no markup between it and the input and if you're not styling it

```
<label>Name: <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="John Doe"></label>
```

is less to output